# Simulation of a pendulum without using the angle with the Euler-Cromer method.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, simulation, eulers-method, machine-precision

I am trying to create a computer simulation of a simple pendulum with a mass $m$ hanging from an inextensible and negligibly massless string, but without using the angle, only using the positions of the constraint $r_2$ on which the mass is hung and of the mass itself $r_1$.

Assuming that the implementation of the simulation in any programming language (in my case javascript) is correct, for the simulation I had thought of using the Euler-Cromer method, already used with the angle obtaining a fairly realistic approximation. While in this case, using the positions of the two elements, I obtain an anomalous behavior. What I start from to find the function $f$ of the method is the image below.

[image: Pendulum simulation]

The force acting on the motion is the tangential component of the gravitational force $\overrightarrow{P_t}$, since the radial component $\overrightarrow{P_r}$ is canceled out by the tension of the string. At this point, to calculate the tangential component, you have to do $\overrightarrow{P_t}=\overrightarrow{P}-\overrightarrow{P_r}$. So

$$
\overrightarrow{P_r}=\frac{\overrightarrow{P}\cdot \overrightarrow{r_{21}}}{|\overrightarrow{r_{21}}|^2}\cdot \overrightarrow{r_{21}}
$$

This is the calculation of the projection of $\overrightarrow{P}$ onto $\overrightarrow{r_{21}}$. Since the string is inextensible, we can say that $|\overrightarrow{r_{21}}|=\mathit{l}$, where $\mathit{l}$ is the length of the string.
$$
\overrightarrow{P_r}=\frac{\overrightarrow{P}\cdot \overrightarrow{r_{21}}}{\mathit{l}^2}\cdot \overrightarrow{r_{21}}
$$

At each step of the algorithm, I always recalculate $\overrightarrow{r_{21}}$ which is $\overrightarrow{r_1}-\overrightarrow{r_2}$. So in the end:
$$
\mathit{f}\left(t,\overrightarrow{r_1}(t)\right)=\overrightarrow{P}-\frac{\overrightarrow{P}\cdot \overrightarrow{r_{21}}}{\mathit{l}^2}\cdot \overrightarrow{r_{21}}
$$

Since $\overrightarrow{P_t}$ is the force, we can say that $\overrightarrow{P_t}=\mathit{f}\left(t,\overrightarrow{r_1}(t)\right)=m\frac{d\overrightarrow{v}(t)}{dt}$ and therefore the steps of the final method are as follows.

$$
\overrightarrow{v_{n+1}}=\overrightarrow{v_n}+\frac{\overrightarrow{P}-\frac{\overrightarrow{P} \cdot \overrightarrow{r_{21_n}}}{\mathit{l}^2}\cdot \overrightarrow{r_{21_n}}}{m}\cdot \Delta t
$$
Where
$$
\overrightarrow{r_{21_n}}=\overrightarrow{r_{1_n}}-\overrightarrow{r_2}
$$
Then
$$
\overrightarrow{r_{1_{n+1}}}=\overrightarrow{r_{1_n}}+\overrightarrow{v_{n+1}}\cdot \Delta t
$$
$$
\overrightarrow{r_{21_{n+1}}}=\overrightarrow{r_{1_{n+1}}}-\overrightarrow{r_2}
$$

Note: $r_2$ is fixed, therefore it is constant. I wanted to know if the mathematical calculations and reasoning are correct, because as shown in the next image (three points of the simulation), the animation is completely unrealistic and inaccurate.

[image]

Where the dashed circle is the trajectory it should follow. As you can see, the simulation is very unrealistic. Mine was just a test to understand if it was possible to simulate this pendulum using the Euler-Cromer method without using the angle. It could be that the method's precision is not accurate enough for the trajectory to be realistic, making it unstable, and perhaps with more advanced methods like Runge-Kutta, the approximation would be better. I also tried the Verlet method, but it doesn't change much. I haven't tried Runge-Kutta yet, but before doing so, I would like to be sure that the problem lies in the precision of the calculations rather than the calculated expressions.

Comment: If it gets better as you decrease $\Delta t$, it is a method accuracy issue. If it persists, it is an implementation issue. Most methods will not exactly preserve $\vert \vec{r}_{21} \vert = 1$ unless you explicitly constrain the system

Comment: IMO the problem is within the two last equations:  
$\overrightarrow{r_{1_{n+1}}}=\overrightarrow{r_{1_n}}+\overrightarrow{v_{n+1}}\cdot \Delta t$  
-- since the velocity is tangent to the dashed circle the resulting $\overrightarrow{r_{1_{n+1}}}$ is no longer pointing to it, that is why (your last equation)  
$\overrightarrow{r_{21_{n+1}}}=\overrightarrow{r_{1_{n+1}}}-\overrightarrow{r_2}$  
the lenght of $\overrightarrow{r_{21_{n+1}}} \gt l$ -- as shown in your graphs.

Comment: Mechanical systems in this form as kinetics under position constraints is a DAE system of index 3. Non-specific solvers, usually multistep, that can be used to also solve DAE systems do this only up to index 2. So you can expect that constraints or hidden constraints will be violated by this method.

Answer (score 0):

I understood the problem. As @m-stgt says, the 'approximate' velocity is not tangent to the circle (I think he wrote it wrong). This generates an error both in the velocity and consequently in the position. To visualize it, I added the velocity vector to the simulation, where it is possible to see that the velocity (in purple) is not parallel to the tangential force (in blue), and the latter is tangent to the dashed circle by construction. Below the image.

[image: velocity visualization]

So could I "rotate" the velocity (without changing the magnitude) so that it is always tangent to the circle, thus reducing the error, or changing to a more precise method where the velocity is always tangent can solve the problem?

Comment: In fact, I meant _tangent_, disregarding you use $\overrightarrow{v_{n+1}}$ not $\overrightarrow{v_{n}}$ to get the new location after $\Delta t$. Nevertheless $\overrightarrow{r_{21_{n+1}}}$ gets longer and longer.

Comment: I don't understand why the vector shouldn't point more towards the center. Perhaps you mean because it's as if I'm not considering the centripetal force? The velocity in rotational motion has a radial and a tangential component, so the fact that the direction of the velocity is tangential to the motion is a prerequisite for the point to follow the characteristic circular motion of the pendulum with an inextensible string.

Comment: "The velocity in rotational motion has a radial and a tangential component" -- Woot? The string of the pendulum is inextensible, isn't it? The motion of the pendulum is _only_ circular, thus the used formulas must reflect this fact. IMO, for this simulation, it would be sufficient to correct the error in $\overrightarrow{r_{1_{n+1}}}=\overrightarrow{r_{1_n}}+\overrightarrow{v_{n+1}}\cdot \Delta t$ in the last step $\overrightarrow{r_{21_{n+1}}}=\overrightarrow{r_{1_{n+1}}}-\overrightarrow{r_2}$ by "pushing back" the pendulum to the _inextensible_ radius of the circle.

Comment: @m-stgt Now I get what you were saying. It's actually more precise than what I had in mind, which was just adjusting the velocity vector's direction (and besides, that still leads to errors in calculating position later on). So, it looks like the issue comes down to how accurate the method itself is, leading to mistakes in plotting the trajectory. Without using angles, but rather positions, there are two ways to go about it: either use a super accurate method or add some kind of workaround to the method, like the one you talked about.

Comment: The first comment from @whpowell96 addressed the problem already, I only pointed to the formulas "in error", tiny but remarkable error. IMO there is still another detail, the velocity -- you use $\overrightarrow{v_{n+1}}\cdot \Delta t$ what is the value at the end of $\Delta t$, but there is an acceleration, how about an average between beginning and end of $\Delta t$, aritmetic mean or geometric, or even AGM? But, more importent me think, that you find out that a pendulum is not a sine oscillator (what not all watch collectors know).

Comment: I tried pushing back the pendulum as you suggested. The simulation is better now, however, even though I read that the Euler-Cromer method is good for energy conservation, it seems that this is not happening. It's as if there is an aerodynamic resistance slowing down the pendulum quickly until it stops. Would applying AGM potentially solve this?

P.S.: For the correction, I calculated the new velocity value, then the new value of $\overrightarrow{r_{21}}$, and then I adjusted $\overrightarrow{r_{21}}$ in this way:
$$
\overrightarrow{r_{21}}_{n+1}=\hat{r_{21}}_n\cdot l
$$
l is radius.

Comment: "It's as if there is an aerodynamic resistance slowing down the pendulum quickly until it stops." -- It stops?? I assume you calculate w/o friction, so it should continue like a perpetual motion machine, get to the same hight to the right as to the left. Then, taking the average of the velocity at the beginning and the end of $\Delta t$ was just an idea to make it "a wee" more realistic. Maybe overdone for a simple simulation.